# Kali Linux VirtualBox Wi-Fi Config

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, kali-linux

So I installed Kali on my mac (laptop) the other day and now I'm stuck with a question:

I cant access the internet. My inet is 127.0.0.1 ... 
I have set up Bridged connection in the virtualbox config and Really don't know what I am doing wrong. 
This probably has to do that I am wireless, but I just don't know what to do... 
I have provided screenshots below. 
[Here's the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUQHU.png) ;
[More Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwTxi.png) ;
I even changed the NetworkManager config, restarted several times yet no solution...

Comment: `127.0.01` won'r route to another machine.  You need to start another interface usually, it will get an address starting `192.168.`..

Answer (score 0):

You will need an external Wifi adapter. Once plugged into your computer, select `Devices` from the menu on the top of the screen (Apple menu?!) and select your interface you want to use. From there, you can use the Internet with the adapter.